# ValueError: Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`. Expected: [0 1 2 ... 1387 1388 1389], got [0 1 2 ... 18609 24127 41850]

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, xgboost, xgbclassifier

**Situation:** I am trying to use XGBoost classifier, however this error pops up to me:
*"ValueError: Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`.  Expected: [0 1 2 ... 1387 1388 1389], got [0 1 2 ... 18609 24127 41850]"*.

**Unlike this solved one**: [Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`. Expected: [0 1 2 3 4 5], got [1 2 3 4 5 6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996617/invalid-classes-inferred-from-unique-values-of-y-expected-0-1-2-3-4-5-got/72132612#72132612), it seems that I have a different scenario which is about not starting from 0.

**Code:**

```
X = data_concat
y = data_concat[['forward_count','comment_count','like_count']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=72)

#Train, test split
print ('Train set:', X_train.shape,  y_train.shape)     #Check the size after split
print ('Test set:', X_test.shape,  y_test.shape)

xgb = XGBClassifier()
clf = xgb.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_metric='auc')  #HERE IS WHERE GET THE ERROR
```

**The Datafrme and frame info is like this:**
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzvUH.png)

[DataFrame Info.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kiEr.png)

**I have adopted** different y, meaning when y has less or more columns, the list "[0 1 2 ... 1387 1388 1389]" will simultaneously shrink or expand.

*If you need further info, please let me know. Appreciate your help :)*

Answer (score 1):

Need to transform the y_train value to fit xgboost, it starts from 0 but not 1.
Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y_train = le.fit_transform(y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your data have same size, but labels of those classes have different values, for example it must be [1,2,3,4] an it returns [1,2,5,6]. It can occur if you firstly encode your data and then drop some those encoded values that belong in some class for some reason.